# reactjs onClick handlers not attaching on IE11 on Windows 8 and 7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reactjs

I'm using React for a project and I'm having this weird issue where my `onClick` handlers are not working on IE11 but only on Windows 8.1 and 7. They work fine in every other browser and on Windows 10. Has anyone run into anything like this before? The code is as simple as

```
<div onClick={ function(event) { console.log(event) } }>A div</div>
```

However, `onMouseUp` and `onMouseDown` events do work. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing `}`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The issue still persists though. I've fixed the typo in the example.

Comment: Have you tried `onClick={this.someFn}` instead of function literal? Shouldn't make a difference though... the JSX transformer you're using is probably not related to exact ReactJS version.

Comment: @Rene, yeah it doesn't make a difference. It seems this was a known bug and was fixed in react v.0.14.2 just a few days ago.

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to be a bug in the latest version of React (v.0.14.1). When I switched it back to v.0.13.3, it worked.

Comment: And the issue is fixed in v.0.14.2

Comment: Nasty error. How come React guys release a version without testing first such critical bugs?

Answer (score 1):

syntax :

try using `<div onClick="function(event) { console.log(event); }">A div</div>`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using React. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the answer when it was answered. Now the OP has added reactjs, which would now make the answer irrelevant. So recommending to delete.